# Numeric and orderable hashsum of a Semver

Tags: algorithm, math, hash, semantic-versioning

I'm working on a system relying on pseudo semver version numbers (only using the major, minor and patch numbers) to index files.

For faster comparisons and lookup and for the fun of doing it this way, I'm trying to compute a numeric "hash" for those version numbers. This numeric hash should have the following property (extreme example following) :

```
Hash(1.0.500) < Hash(1.1.0) < Hash(1.3000.0) < Hash(2.0.0)
```

I've already tried a wide range of solutions like weighting each position or like this

```
 int hash = 17;
 hash = hash * 42 + Major;
 hash = hash * 42 + Minor;
 hash = hash * 42 + Patch;
```

But all of these can quickly reach the limitation (following the multiplicator or weight) where

```
Hash(1.0.1500) > Hash(1.1.0)
```

I could have chosen a dirty way and go for a big multiplicator to avoid such collisions (and ensure a minimum number of combinations) but I'd prefer to choose a cleaner path

Is this even possible ?

Comment: Do u have any size limitation for every part of the index?

Comment: I wanted to avoid introducing a size limitation but regarding Henry's response I think I'll have to

Comment: Some architectures, like Google App Engine, require a single (long) number that identifies your version. Therefore, you have to convert the semantic version into a number. I have benn using major*10000+minor*100+patch. Of course, this limits you to 99 paches for each minor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you try to do is to convert a version number with three components (lexicographically ordered) to a single natural number such that the order is preserved. This is not really a hash.

This is trivial if there is an upper bound on the size of the components. Just use a multiplicator larger than the maximum component value.

If there is no such upper bound it is not possible. Consider 0.1.0 is mapped to number N, then all versions 0.0.x must be mapped to numbers smaller N which is impossible if there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, another idea I had was to use the whole group or versions to find out the multiplicator which is also dumb as any version added later to the group could break the logic.
I know that this is not a hash in it pure sense (that's why it's surrounded by quotes) :). Anyway thanks for the answer